# Auto completing textfield in jsp?

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, textfield, jsp-tags

Hi guys im trying to make a web application by using apache tomcat as my local server. can anyone help me find a way to get "auto complete" option while inputing into a textfield. I want to use it for the purpose of searching items from a big database. Im a beginner trying to learn.
Thank you.

Comment: Autocompletation is a typical client-side task: do you want use only JSP tags/taglib or a JS library/framework can be ok, for you?

Comment: I think i will stick with JSP for a while. Is there a way in JSP?